# How to implement SignalR Core Hub function on Android?

Tags: android, asp.net, kotlin, signalr, signalr-hub

I have been trying to implement SignalR on my android app. Referred (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/java-client?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

SignalR version: `implementation 'com.microsoft.signalr:signalr:7.0.0`

```
private var hubConnection: HubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder
         .create(serverUrl)
         .build()

fun startConnection() {

    val customClassType: Type = object : TypeReference<UserStatus>() {}.type

    hubConnection.on("SetUserStatus", { message: UserStatus ->
        Log.d(TAG, "New hub message: ${message.userId}")
    }, customClassType)

    hubConnection.start().blockingAwait()
    Log.d(TAG, "hubConnection.connectionState: ${hubConnection.connectionState}") // this prints CONNECTED
```

However, My `SetUserStatus` handler is never triggered. `serverUrl` is something like: `wss://xxxx.yyyy.com/signalr`.

`UserState` class looks like below,

```
data class UserStatus(

   @SerializedName("userId")
   val userId: Int,

   @SerializedName("status")
   val status: Int

)
```

Connection is started on `Application` class.

```
class BaseApplication : Application(), LifecycleObserver {

    private lateinit var signalRService: SignalRService

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle.addObserver(this)

        signalRService = SignalRService(applicationContext, SignalRService.SERVER_URL)
        signalRService.startConnection()
    }
}
```

I have done this on iOS and it works when the server triggers the relevant hub method. I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong on android. Any help would be much appreciated!
`